# Is it possible to pass Java-Enum as argument from cucumber feature file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, enums, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am currently using selenium with Java,And want to implement cucumber to make test script more readable.
Currently facing issue while passing argument to java method where Enum is expected as parameter.
I would also like to know if there are any other known limitations of cucumber-java before migrating current framework.

Comment: Have you tried using transforms?

Comment: @DaveMcNulla no I've not used transforms. can you give me example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is: Yes

You can use all kind of different types in your scenario: primitive types, own classes (POJOs), enums, ...

Scenario :

```
Feature: Setup Enum and Print value
      In order to manage my Enum
      As a System Admin
      I want to get the Enum

      Scenario: Verify Enum Print
      When I supply enum value "GET"
```

Step definition code :

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class EnumTest {

    @When("^I supply enum value \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_supply_enum_value(TestEnum arg1) throws Throwable {
        testMyEnum(arg1);
    }

    public enum TestEnum {
        GET,
        POST,
        PATCH
    }

    protected void testMyEnum(TestEnum testEnumValue) {

        switch (testEnumValue) {
            case GET:
                System.out.println("Enum Value GET");
                break;
            case POST:
                System.out.println("Enum Value POST");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Enum Value PATCH");
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Let me know how you are doing. I could try to help you.

Comment: **thanks**
Actually  here you are passing argument in String format                **e.g. When I supply enum value "GET"**
my question was that is it possible to pass argument using enum  **e.g.  When I supply enum value 'testEnum.GET'** like we use in java.
But now i think it is not possible,I've to pass exact String value which is defined in enum.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is not possible technically in Java. You need to tell function what type of value will accept.

Comment: You can for example us it this way:
`When i select MONDAY in the dropdown`
Where MONDAY is from WeekDay enum.
And with the Method
`@When("^i select (SUNDAY|MONDAY|TUESDAY|WEDNESDAY|THURSDAY|FRIDAY|SATURDAY) in the dropdown")
    public void iCheckTheCheckboxSelectOpeningHours(CheckoutAddAddressesPage.WeekDay day)....`
But you cannot use *'enum.enumValue'*

Comment: Well, in theory, you could use a `Transformer`, do a split at the dot, and run a `Class.forName()` on it... But why cause yourself that sort of headache? Not only do you have to specify the exact `enum` constant that way (e.g. `MONDAY`); you'll also have to specify the class name (and packages) precisely (e.g. `com.example.WeekDay`). The built-in facility shown above will turn a String into the right `enum` type on the fly, as long as the String matches the `enum` constant exactly; for matching differently, e.g. based on `enum` values, you can use a `Transformer`, as mentioned previously...

Comment: While this answer is correct, I created a new question with a more complex example, which - given the nature of cucumber as a tool to communicate with stakeholders - I feel is a good addition to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898427/is-it-possible-to-pass-java-enum-as-argument-from-cucumber-feature-file-in-a-mo

Comment: Starting from cucumber 4.2.0, you need to use the regexp `(.*)` so that it is recognized by the default transformer, see https://cucumber.io/blog/announcing-cucumber-jvm-4-2-0/

Answer (score 6):

This youtube lecture of about 11 minutes gives a good way of doing it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N_ca6lStrU

For example,

```
// enum, obviously in a separate file,
public enum MessageBarButtonType {
    Speak, Clear, Delete, Share
}

// method for parameter type. if you want to use a different method name, you could do @ParameterType(name="newMethodName", value="Speak|Clear|Delete|Share") according to the video.
@ParameterType("Speak|Clear|Delete|Share")
public MessageBarButtonType MessageBarButtonType(String buttonType) {
  return MessageBarButtonType.valueOf(buttonType);
}

// use like this. the name inside {} should match the name of method, though I just used the type name.
@Then("Select message bar {MessageBarButtonType} button")
public void select_message_bar_button(MessageBarButtonType buttonType) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First register a transformer based on an ObjectMapper, then you can just use enums as would be expected.

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

@DefaultParameterTransformer
@DefaultDataTableEntryTransformer
@DefaultDataTableCellTransformer
public Object defaultTransformer(Object fromValue, Type toValueType) {
    JavaType javaType = objectMapper.constructType(toValueType);
    return objectMapper.convertValue(fromValue, javaType);
}

Scenario: No.6 Parameter scenario enum
    Given the professor level is ASSOCIATE


@Given("the professor level is {}")
public void theProfessorLevelIs(ProfLevels level) {
    System.out.println(level);
    System.out.println("");
}

public enum ProfLevels {
    ASSISTANT, ASSOCIATE, PROFESSOR
}
```

[Source](https://ghchirp.tech/1586/)

Comment: Please include some explanation along with your code. Just a bunch of code is not a good answer.

Comment: This also does automatic datarow to object AND Java8 date conversions \o/

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```java
package com.example;

import io.cucumber.java.ParameterType;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @ParameterType("FOO|BAR")
    public Book book(String bookName) {
        return Book.valueOf(bookName);
    }   

    @Given("{book} is my favorite book")
    public void this_is_my_favorite_book(Book book) {
        // step implementation
    }
}
```

Make sure the name of the method annotated with `@ParameterType` matches the name of your placeholder in the step (`book`).

Answer (score -1):

This is no more supported in latest `io.cucumber` maven group
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1393

Comment: It works again: https://cucumber.io/blog/2018/10/31/announcing-cucumber-jvm-4-2-0