# Is it possible to pass Java-Enum as argument from cucumber feature file (in a more text friendly way)?

Tags: java, enums, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Building up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718083/is-it-possible-to-pass-java-enum-as-argument-from-cucumber-feature-file/34754411), the example provided seems to lock the text in the feature file too much to Java programming style (notice that the text is written in all uppercase, and is only one word.

Is it possible to pass enums when the feature file has more "human readable" text? E.g.:

**Simple Example**

```
Feature: Setup Enum and Print value
  In order to manage my Enum
  As a System Admin
  I want to get the Enum

  Scenario Outline: Verify Enum Print
  When I supply a more human readable text to be converted to <Enum>

  Examples: Text can have multiple formats
  |Enum         |
  |Christmas    |
  |New Year Eve |
  |independence-day|
```

I reckon the enum could be something like:

```
public enum Holiday {

CHRISTMAS("Christmas"),NEW_YEAR("New Year"),INDEPENDENCE_DAY("independence-day");

private String extendedName;

private Holidays(String extendedName) {
    this.extendedName = extendedName;
}

}
```

How could we convert one from the other?

**More complex example**

In a more complex example, we would pass this onto a ScenarioObject

```
Scenario: Enum within a Scenario Object
      When I supply a more human readable text to be converted in the objects: 
      |Holiday         |Character|
      |Christmas    |Santa  |
      |New Year Eve |Harry|
      |independence-day|John Adams|

public class ScenarioObject{
private String character;
private Holiday holiday;
(...getters and setters)
}
```

**Update:**
If the only solution is to apply a `Transformer`, [as described here](https://static.javadoc.io/info.cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.5/cucumber/api/Transformer.html), an example of how this would be a applied to the `ScenarioObject` would be appreciated, since simply tagging the enum with a `@XStreamConverter(HolidayTransformer.class)` is not sufficient for the transformer to work within the `ScenarioObject`.

Comment: What is the cucumber version? cucumber 2?

Comment: @Grasshopper 1.2.5 . Is this very different in 2?

Comment: It is pretty easy with cucumber 2. Refer to this - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1010. And a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565284/cucumber-not-serializing-date-string-from-datatable-in-feature-file-to-a-localda/49571456#49571456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found for this so far was with a transformer.
In the case of the complex example with `ScenarioObject`,this involves:

**Mark enum with converter**

```
@XStreamConverter(HolidayTransformer.class)
public enum Holiday {

CHRISTMAS("Christmas"),NEW_YEAR("New Year"),INDEPENDENCE_DAY("independence-day");

private String extendedName;

private Holidays(String extendedName) {
this.extendedName = extendedName;
}

public static Holiday fromString(String type) throws Exception {...}
}
```

**Create the transformer**

```
public class HolidayTransformer  extends Transformer<Holiday> {

@Override
public Holiday transform(String value) {
    try {
        return Holiday.fromString(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Could not convert from value");
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

**Mark the ScenarioObject with the transformer as well**

```
public class ScenarioObject{
private String character;
@XStreamConverter(HolidayTransformer.class)
private Holiday holiday;
(...getters and setters)
}
```